# Keycloak Redirect URI is adding port zero to the url

Tags: reverse-proxy, keycloak, wildfly-10, undertow, wildfly-11

Encountered redirect_uri error in keycloak. Found same issue logged at JIRA [KEYCLOAK-7237](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-7237), just want to check any work around? Anyone can help? Thank you in advance.

2018-06-30 11:34:13,996 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-8) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=Victz, clientId=portal, userId=null, ipAddress=, error=invalid_redirect_uri, redirect_uri=https://www.example.com:0/home

I am using apache http reverse proxy running on centos7, wildly 10, keycloak 3.4.3. has also tried in below environment but same error.

Tried in 
wildly 10, wildly 11, jboss 7.1,
Keycloak 3.4.3 as well as keycloak 4.0

Also tried shutdown apache http and access directly to http://www.example.org:8080/home , but seems return_uri automatically been converted to https with port 0.

Please see below standalone.xml, tried removed below proxy-peer and request-dumper config but no luck.

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:4.0">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" proxy-address-forwarding="true" enable-http2="true"/>
            <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" proxy-address-forwarding="true" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <location name="/drive" handler="drive"/>
                <access-log pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{i,Referer}&quot; &quot;%{i,User-Agent}&quot; &quot;%{i,COOKIE}&quot; &quot;%{o,SET-COOKIE}&quot; %S &quot;%I %T&quot;" prefix="access."/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
            </host>
            <host name="example1" alias="example.com1,www.example.com1" default-web-module=“example1-0.1.war">
                <location name="/drive" handler="drive”/>
                <filter-ref name="proxy-peer"/>
                <filter-ref name="request-dumper" priority="30"/>
            </host>
            <host name="example2" alias="example.com2,www.example.com2" default-web-module="example2-0.1.war">
                <location name="/drive" handler="drive"/>
                <filter-ref name="proxy-peer"/>
                <filter-ref name="request-dumper" priority="30"/>
            </host>
            <host name="example3" alias="example.com3,www.example.com3" default-web-module="example3-0.1.war">
                <location name="/drive" handler="drive"/>
                <filter-ref name="proxy-peer"/>
                <filter-ref name="request-dumper" priority="30"/>
            </host>

        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            <file name="drive" path="/app/drive"/>
        </handlers>
        <filters>
            <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="JBoss-EAP/7"/>
            <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
            <filter name="proxy-peer" class-name="io.undertow.server.handlers.ProxyPeerAddressHandler" module="io.undertow.core"/>
            <filter name="request-dumper" class-name="io.undertow.server.handlers.RequestDumpingHandler" module="io.undertow.core"/>
        </filters>
    </subsystem>
```

Comment: I have same problem. I dont know if :0 port comes from java adapter (In my case keycloak proxy) or from misconfigurated client in keycloak.

There is also  proxy-address-forwarding="true" option in keycloak listener and at least in keycloak proxy is proxy-address-forwarding parameter. But this will influence behaviour of host forwarding, not port. 

Keycloak is listening on https:8443, keycloakproxy on http:8080

Comment: @Shawn - Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue. I'm using an nginx reverse proxy on centos 7.

Answer (score 6):

**Context**

When using Keycloak's [Spring Boot client adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_boot_adapter) behind a reverse proxy, the URL query parameter `redirect_uri` set by [OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/adapters/oidc/adapter-core/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java) may contain a port suffix `:0` due to incomplete or false configuration.

**Basic Problem**

In order to construct the `redirect_uri`, the Spring Boot app needs to guess its public URL, including at least protocol and hostname, and possibly also the IP port. Behind a reverse proxy, this requires cooperation with the proxy, and/or explicit configuration.

**Explanation for the :0**

The `:0`, if present, was probably set by [OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/eacc95b6998cd16d8a0574660946ee7d8727b527/adapters/oidc/adapter-core/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java#L153) (This loose handling may be considered a bug, but in the present case stems from incomplete configuration.): Keycloak recognized that the Spring Boot app is talking HTTPS, but it found no HTTPS port configuration, so it defaulted to zero.

**Solution Steps**

Assuming that:

- this is about a Spring Boot app
- running behind a reverse proxy
- acting as a Keycloak client

you need to ensure following things to solve the problem:

1. configure the reverse proxy to add following headers

   - `x-forwarded-for` telling the hostname
   - `x-forwarded-proto` telling whether the connection is secure or not
2. configure the Spring Boot app to act correctly

   - just read the current Spring Boot ["How-to" Guide on running behind a proxy server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-use-behind-a-proxy-server) (one concise screen page)
3. configure [Keycloak's Spring Boot adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_java_adapter_config)

   - maybe you need to explicitly set the `confidential-port` to `443`

**Trouble-Shooting/Cross Check**

Only one point: Assuming that this is about a Spring Boot app behind a reverse proxy, you should be able to use `tcpdump` or similar to monitor the unencrypted traffic (like `-i lo -s0 -A`) and see the HTTP headers. Any requests sent to the Spring Boot app should feature the headers required according to the Spring Boot Security How-to mentioned above (`x-forwarded-for` and `x-forwarded-proto`), otherwise, the proxy is misconfigured.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same exact problem. My spring boot app sits behind nginx. I updated nginx to pass through the x-forwarded headers and updated the spring boot config with

spring boot yaml config:

```
server:
  use-forward-headers: true    

keycloak:
  realm: myrealm
  public-client: true
  resource: myclient
  auth-server-url: https://sso.example.com:443/auth
  ssl-required: external
  confidential-port: 443
```

nginx config:

```
upstream app {
   server 1.2.3.4:8042 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=60s;
   server 1.2.3.5:8042 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=60s;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ...

    location / {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port   443;

        proxy_next_upstream     error timeout invalid_header http_500;
        proxy_connect_timeout   2;

        proxy_pass          http://app;
    }
}
```

The specific change that made it work for me was adding `keycloak.confidential-port`. Once I added that it was no longer adding port 0 in the redirect_uri.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the similar issue. To make it work I have updated standalone.xml as below

Server config

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" allow-unescaped-characters-in-url="true" redirect-socket="https" proxy-address-forwarding="true" enable-http2="true"/>
```

SSO config

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1">
<realm name="myrealm">
<auth-server-url>https://sso.example.com:443/auth</auth-server-url>
<ssl-required>external</ssl-required>
<enable-cors>true</enable-cors>
<confidential-port>0</confidential-port>
</realm>
<secure-deployment name="mywar.war">
<realm>myrealm</realm>
<ssl-required>external</ssl-required>
<resource>myclient</resource>
<public-client>true</public-client>
</secure-deployment>
</subsystem>
```