# Attempting to connect Spring-Boot app to Keycloak with SSL

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, katacoda

I am working on a Katacoda scenario in which I connect a spring-boot application to a KeyCloak. I wanted to make it pretty minimal so here are my configs:

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Application Properties

```
#Keycloak Properties
#Katcoda Url
keycloak.auth-server-url=https://2886795315-8444-ollie02.environments.katacoda.com/auth
keycloak.realm=todoRealm
#Client
keycloak.resource=openid-login-client
keycloak.public-client=true
```

My issue is when I hit an endpoint on my application it redirects correctly to the login page. But the problem is that the `redirect_uri` it passes in is not ssl so `http://2886795315-8080-ollie02.environments.katacoda.com/v1/todos` which causes a CORs issue.

I added this property to try to force https:

```
keycloak.ssl-required=all
```

But then it changes the `redirect_uri` param it is passing into the keycloak login to `https://2886795315-8080-ollie02.environments.katacoda.com:0/v1/todos`

Does anyone have any idea why the url path has `:0` appended to the front?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51121234/keycloak-redirect-uri-is-adding-port-zero-to-the-url).

This is part of the Keycloak security defaults where it is promoting using a non-standard port for the SSL connection. This can be set in the Keycloak environment with the `KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_PORT=4443` for example.

For the application (client) this can then require that (when for example `ssl-required=all` is set) the application will need to know this port (i.e. whatever the the `KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_PORT` is set as). To explicitly set this port in the application, so that it does not default to `:0` use the `keycloak.confidential-port=4443` property.

Because you are using nginx then this can of course be handled by a proxy pass directive in which case it is simply to set the `keycloak.confidential-port` property to a standard 443 for SSL.

Not to over-complicate things, but you could of course use a seperate proxy-pass directive for a non-standard port in NginX that would handle the client SSL connections to the Keycloak back-end.

(remind me to please find the documentation links for this answer)... I haven't the time right now.